# Change Focal Length on the fly (Scrool Wheel or Custom Shortcut) in The 3D View/Walk Mode/Fly Mode

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I found no shortcut to change the 3d viewport focal length and I cannot create one by right clicking on the Focal Length bouton. I think this possibility exists with Python lines but I am having difficulty finding the correct line of code and have never been able to execute anything relating to the viewport.

I heard about :
SpaceView3d.lens

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Friendly